# List all active websocket connections using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket

Currently I am working with client websocket connections using JavaScript and I wanted to list out all the active websocket connections that my page has made. I am using the below JS code for making the connection.

```
var startconnection = () => {
            try {
                SOCKET_OBJ = new WebSocket(SOC_URL);   
            } catch (error) {
                document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML += error+"<br />";
            }
            SOCKET_OBJ.onopen = () => {
                console.log("connection established..");
                document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML += "Connection Established..<br />";
            }

            SOCKET_OBJ.onmessage = (event) => {
                console.log(event.data);
                document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML += event.data+"<br />";
            }
       }
```

Note:- I don't want to use the object name for listing out the socket names.